# How can I draw an oval using jbuttons and actionlistener?

Tags: java, swing, japplet, jcreator

I looked into some of the other questions that may have already been answered and i didn't see anything related to mine, or at least that I understood.

I'm trying to create a traffic light and what i am having trouble with is the actual drawing of the red green and yellow circles when I click on a button. A speedy answer would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
public class TrafficLight extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

   private Image Hayden;

    JButton btn1;

    JButton btn2;

    JButton btn3;

    int x;

public void init() {

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    btn1 = new JButton("Stop");

    btn2 = new JButton("Wait");

    btn3 = new JButton("Go");

    Boolean Answer;

    add(btn1);

    btn1.addActionListener(this);

    add(btn2);

    btn2.addActionListener(this);

    add(btn3);

    btn3.addActionListener(this);

    Hayden = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "49.jpg");
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

    if (event.getSource()==btn1){
        boolean one = true;
    }
    if (event.getSource()==btn2){
        boolean two = true;
    }
    if (event.getSource()==btn3){
        boolean three = true;
    }
    repaint();

}
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    super.paint(g);

    g.setColor(Color.black);

    g.drawRect(0, 400, 700, 200);//creating the rectangle
    g.fillRect(0, 400, 700, 200);

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(645, 0, 55, 155);//creating the rectangle
    g.fillRect(645, 0, 55, 155);

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawOval(650, 5, 45, 45);//creating the oval
    g.fillOval(650, 5, 45, 45);

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawOval(650, 55, 45, 45);//creating the oval
    g.fillOval(650, 55, 45, 45);

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawOval(650, 105, 45, 45);//creating the oval
    g.fillOval(650, 105, 45, 45);
    if (one == true){
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawOval(650,5,45,45);
    }
    else if (two == true){
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawOval(650,55,45,45);
    }
    else if (three == true){
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawOval(650,105,45,45);
    }
    g.drawImage(Hayden, 0, 500, 150, 100, this);//create the image

}


}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with javascript or javascript events.

Answer (score 1):

`isSelected()` methods is more related to toggle buttons. In your case inside `actionPerformed()` none of the conditions will ever return true. Quick and dirty fix could be to check the source of the event, ie:

```
if (event.getSource() == btn1){
    x = 5;
}
```

Cleaner would be:

```
btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        x = 5;
    }
});
```

Another note, do you custom painting on JPanel or JComponent and then add the component to the content pane of JApplet. See [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for details.

Also, it is recommended to use a layout manager rather than absolute layout. Check out [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more info on that.

Make sure to go through [How to Make Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html) tutorial for general guidelines.

***EDIT: regarding***

> cut it down a bit, hopefullynotworse }

Your last edit is incorrect, it does not compile. You're declaring local variable `boolean one = true;` and trying to use it in another method. Make `boolean one` a member of the class. Same with `two` and `three` variables.

Comment: hmm, does this still use if then statements then? i need to implement  if, else if, or switch for the requirements

Comment: cut it down a bit, hopefullynotworse
 }

Comment: @user1547182 if you want to keep a single `ActionListener` for all buttons, then just fix the existing `if` statements. Otherwise, you can add separate `ActionListener` for each button.

Comment: @user1547182 you last edit is incorrect, it does not compile. You're declaring local variable `boolean one = true;` and trying to use it in another method. Make `boolean one` a member of the class.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you need to be wary about is variable scope. The booleans one, two, and three have a scope within their respective if statement. If you make these booleans instance variables (create the variables at the top of the class like int x and your buttons) then their scopes are the entire class, and they can be referenced in each method.

```
JButton btn2;
JButton btn3;
boolean one, two three;
```

As of right now, these booleans cannot be accessed by anything, including the paint method, that isn't in their respective if statement.